# Dynamic form with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form for my Item model for it's :make attribute. Based on the option chosen it should render the corresponding Products that share the same :item_make value. So if you select "Hoodies" on the first form, the different hooded sweatshirts available would show on the second. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

quote

```
attr_accessible :items_attributes
has_many :items
```

product

```
attr_accessible :name, :item_make
has_many :items
```

item

```
attr_accessible :make, :product_id
belongs_to :quote
belongs_to :product
```

the two inputs:(inside nested quote form -> Item form)

```
<%= f.input :make, collection: clothing_types, label: 'Thread Type', remote: true, 
url: url_for(controller: 'quotes', action: 'update_products'), 
type: 'json', input_html: {class: "select_make"} %> 

<%= f.input :product_id, input_html: {class: "select_product"} %>
```

Currently @products is the list of all products.

quotes_Controller:

```
def new
  @quote = Quote.new
  @quote.items.build
  @item = Item.new
  @products = Product.all
end

def update_products
  @make = params[:make]
  @subproducts = Product.where(:item_make => @make).all
  render json: @subproducts.map{|x| [x.id, x.name]}
end
```

**EDIT:**Application.js

```
$(document).on('change', '.select_make', function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/quotes/update_products",
        success: function(data) {
        if (data.content == 'None') 
            {
            $('.select_product').empty();
            $('.select_product').append( $('<option>No make provided!</option>'));
            }
        else
            $('.select_product').empty();
            $('.selecT_product').append(); //unfinished
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried using different variations of the jquery here [Ruby on Rails - drop down box on change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863990/ruby-on-rails-drop-down-box-on-change-event) but haven't been able to get it to work yet.

If anyone could enlighten me on the javascript needed to do this, that would be awesome

Comment: You shared none of Your JS/Coffescript code, start with that. Also it's not clear how Your models to each other, it is important if You want to use mass-assignment with nested attributes.

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons I added the models and javascript code. What I would like to do is render or append subproducts to the .select_product class, or learn of any better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing something like this :

```
def update_products
  @make = params[:make]
  @subproducts = Product.where(:item_make => @make).all
  respond_with json: @subproducts.map{|x| [x.id, x.name]}
end


$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/quotes/update_products.json",
    // Rest of the code....
});
```

Comment: if thats the correct syntax for the url then thank you, however my real issue is returning the modified array of products