# Simple_form and association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @request,  html: {class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :initiator, label: 'initiator'  %>
  <%= f.association :department, collection: Department.all, value_method: :id, label:   'Назначить на отдел' %>
  <%= f.association :user, collection: User.all, label_method: :email, label: 'Ответственный' %>
  <%= f.input :comment, label: 'comment' %>
  <%= f.input :sla, label: 'SLA' %>
  <%= f.button :submit, label: 'Создать', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

How can I make the association:
If I choose "Department 1" from: Department, the choice of the :user will only users who belong to this department. (When you open the drop-down list were only people from the Department 1, not Users.all) What parameters I have to pass the rails?

Comment: I hope this should help you,

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863990/ruby-on-rails-drop-down-box-on-change-event

Comment: This should also help http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

Comment: Or if you have a subscription http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if it is possible only using simple_form

Try http://www.petermac.com/rails-3-jquery-and-multi-select-dependencies/

I would advice against loading all users in DOM, use an ajax action to filter users if they are many