# Updating dependent list in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have the following problem trying to update a dependant list in rails

```
    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <%= a.label :country %>
                                <br>
                                <%= a.collection_select :country, @countries, :id, :name, {prompt: " Select a Country"}, {:id => 'countries_select'} %>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <%= a.label :state %>
                                <br>
                                <%= a.collection_select :state, @states, :id, :name, {prompt: " Select a State"}, {:id => 'states_select'} %>
                            </div>
                            <script>

                                $("#countries_select").change(function() {
                                    alert($(this).val());
                                    //$("#states_select").find("option").remove().end()
                                    var url = 'update_states?country_id=' + $(this).val()


                                });
                            </script>
```

this is a the part where i select the country_id (have an alert for test that.

```
def update_states
```

# updates artists and songs based on genre selected
    country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    # map to name and id for use in our options_for_select

```
@states=country.states.map{|a| [a.name, a.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Country")
#options = @states.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Country")
#render :text => "{#{options.join(",")}}"
```

end

This is the code in the application helper, but it does nothing... any ideas?

Comment: try this https://github.com/arvindvyas/Country-State-Select

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863990/ruby-on-rails-drop-down-box-on-change-event